# drupal context path and subpaths

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a problem with Context path condition. I would like on the conditions region to assign something like path/* where * indicates all its subpaths. For instance, if we have path/subpath1/subpath2 the context condition should match on path, subpath1 and subpath2.

Is it possible to do that on Context?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't [cross-post questions](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83067/context-path-and-subpaths), thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use **[ContextPHP](https://drupal.org/project/contextphp) module** to add php for Conditions. The same way you are using php for Vivilibiliy paths of a block. Example:

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79512/tokens-in-blocks-configuration-for-list-only-pages/80155#80155